# NodeJS: Spawn child process, and capture stdout of grandchild process?

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process, steam

I'm trying to start a process with NodeJS `child_process`, and that process itself spawns another process. I am trying to capture the grandchild process stdout or detect it closing. A few issues arise.

1. My program does not know the executable's filename. (Unable to use tasklist)
2. The child process instantly closes after starting the grandchild process.

```js
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

let childProcess = spawn('pathToExe', ['exeArgs'], {stdio: 'pipe'});
childProcess.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  // Here I can capture the child process STDOUT
  // The child process closes instantly after spawning the 'grandchild'
});
```

How can I see what subprocesses the child process spawns, and detect when it closes or exits?

Comment: Can't you use `exec` instead?

Comment: @ariel even with `exec` the problem still arises of obtaining the subprocesses.